# Row width child causes Center parent to expand

Tags: flutter-layout

This is my code for the layout:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Choose category'),
            Container(
              child: CategoryCards(),
            ),
            Row(
              // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text('Recommended'),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Text('See All'),
                    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)
```

I want the "See All ->" text to be on the right side but when I set
`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`  `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` stops working [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yxwm.jpg) and when I unset it the ***Center*** widget expands. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F72ky.jpg)

Image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QVRe.jpg) is the desired result where "Se all ->" is on the right and ***Center*** widget still contains everything

[image: before row width]
[image: after row width]
[image: desired]

Comment: you like to use `MainAxisSize.min,` and to show the widget apart?  Can you include an image you are trying to get

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the following code is working:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Choose category'),
            Container(
              child: CategoryCards(),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Recommended'),
                Spacer(),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('See All'),
                    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)
```